# How to fix infinite loop and functions in tkinter typing test?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

Let me start off by saying I know I have several problems and errors with this code, but I am have been searching for answers and trying to solve them for many days now.
I am trying to make a basic typing test app, which calculates wpm and errors. It should last for sixty seconds on the main screen, and then an end screen should appear with your score.
My problems are:

- I can't get the input from the Text widget.
- My start time for the length of the test restarts with every iteration of the loop.
- The main problem is getting the three main functions to work together, since one of them needs a while loop, but I cannot have the function with the while loop within the `tk.mainloop()`, or else it creates an infinite loop and my program breaks. If I nest the `end_screen()` and `wpm_calc()` functions in the `main_screen()` function, it makes the variables accessible, but the problem with the `wpm_calc()` function is the looping, and with the `end_screen()` function it is creating the new window and destroying the main one, as well as using the restart button.

I have tried some workaround with variables defined outside the functions, with global variables, and with nesting or combining the functions in various ways, none of which have worked. For the Text.get(), I have tried using `text_area.get('1.0','end-1c')`. This also hasn't worked.

This is close to a minimal working example.

```
def main_screen():
    tk=Tk()
    tk.title('Typing Test')
    tk.geometry('800x500')
    tk.iconbitmap('typing test.ico')
    main_title=Label(tk,text='1 Minute Typing Test',font=('Times',36))
    main_title.pack(pady=5)
    directions=Label(tk,text='Start Typing to Begin!',font=('Times',14))
    directions.pack()
    base_text=Label(tk,text=randomizer(),bg='#E0E0EE',font=('Helvetica',12),wraplength=600,justify=LEFT)
    base_text.pack(pady=10)
    text_area=Text(tk,font=('Times',14),width=72,height=8,wrap='word')
    text_area.pack()
    target_text=randomizer()
    typed_text=[]
    wpm=0
    errors=0
    start_time=time.time()
    while True:
        time_elapsed=max(time.time()-start_time,1)
        if time_elapsed==60:
            break
        wpm=round((len(typed_text)/(time_elapsed/60))/5)
        key=text_area.get(0.0,END)
        typed_text.append(key)
        for x in typed_text:
            if x != target_text:
                errors += 1
    end_screen()

def end_screen():
    tk.destroy()
    end=Tk()
    end.title('Typing Test')
    end.geometry('800x500')
    end.iconbitmap('typing test.ico')
    main_title=Label(end,text='Test Over',font=('Times',36))
    main_title.pack(pady=10)
    speed=Label(end,text='WPM: '+str(wpm),font=('Times',20))
    speed.pack(padx=10,pady=5)
    accuracy=Label(end,text='Errors: '+str(errors),font=('Times',20))
    accuracy.pack(padx=10,pady=5)
    restart=Button(end,text='Click to Restart',padx=10,pady=10,fg='white',bg='black',command=main_screen)
    restart.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
    end.mainloop()

main_screen()
```

Comment: One Tk() will do entire script you're duplicated.. Same as mainloop() too

Comment: Providing more of the code would help. As for your text widget use ´textwidget.get(0.0, END)´. For your loop problem you may be able to workaround with threads and global variables.

Comment: Thank you @toyotaSupra for the advice. I combined the main_screen() and wpm_calc() functions into one, and used tk.update().

Comment: I have now resolved all problems with this question, except for getting crazy wpm and errors values using Text.get(1.0,'end-1c'). Thanks for your help @AJ